# Default route problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I want to hit a url like 
http://localhost:8080/controllername 
I want the "Index" action to be the default action called. I assumed the default route mapping would be fine and the "Index" action would be called on whatever controller was specified - seems I need to specify 
http://localhost:8080/controllername/index

Is this correct?

Mapping:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Can we see your other routes? Perhaps others are taking priority?

Comment: I have this route set up and the url that's displayed to access this is http://localhost:4765/
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Customers", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: @hoakney I have normally used the same route too. I only have one route mapping as above and get a 404 I try to access http://localhost:8080/cms as apposed to http://localhost:8080/cms/index

Comment: @spender - no other routes mapped!

Comment: This looks like a problem with you server. You're running your own IIS as far as I can see. Try running the same app with VS's development server and report if you're still having the same problem.

Comment: Running in VS Dev server. Will post any findings

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying should definitely work. In fact, the code you posted is from the default templates, and I've just tested it by adding an "Index" action to the AccountController and visiting /Account in my browser.

I'd recommend creating a new project and testing this behaviour (first with the built-in web server, then with IIS, if you're not always using the built-in server). If it works, there's probably something different in your project that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it occured because of a collision with a directory in the project. I had a structure like this in my project:

```
Controllers \
             HomeController.cs
             CmsController.cs
Cms \
     WhateverFile.cs
```

The `Cms` subdirectory collided with the `/Cms` URL, while `Cms/Index` worked. I simply renamed my colliding folder name. If you have to keep it, there is a [`RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx) that can be used to prevent automatic lookup of files. If that is enabled I think that a lot exclusions have to be added for the Script etc, see [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/03/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-2.aspx) for an example.